# SQL procedure from Excel run from connection properties with user login as parameter

Tags: sql-server, excel

I want to run a SQL procedure from Excel. I want to do it by setting **connection properties** with `command type` as SQL. Here is a good example:
http://datapigtechnologies.com/blog/index.php/running-a-sql-stored-procedure-from-excel-with-dynamic-parameters/

How can I get user login and insert it to a specially prepared `dbo.login_history_table`? How should be written `command text` of Connection Properties.

I am looking for something like:

```
EXECUTE dbo.procedure_who_gets_here ORIGINAL_LOGIN()
```

where ORIGINAL_LOGIN() is a parameter.

**Update.** Here is the code of a stored procedure.

```
create procedure procedure_who_gets_here
(
@UserLogin as varchar(255)
)
as
begin

-- part one, get user data
insert into dbo.LoginsHistory
select 
getdate(), 
ORIGINAL_LOGIN(), -- if ORIGINAL_LOGIN() worked, the @UserLogin would be superfluous
@UserLogin

-- part two, show user what he has to see
select * from dbo.MyTable

end
```

Comment: Is this the user that is logged into the computer that Excel is running under, or is this the user that is logged into the database?

Comment: Why not just use ORIGINAL_LOGIN inside the procedure?

Comment: @JNevill The user is logged into the computer that Excel is running. And although the user is homosapiens he has no idea what SQL is. Neither the connection properties. He is not using Managment Studio and he is not logged into SQL database. User is just a user.

Comment: @SeanLange Procedure works fine as long as you use it only for select statement. I have no idea how to combine SELECT with INSERT in one procedure. INSERT alone does not work.

Comment: Unless you can provide some details other than "it doesn't work" there is nothing anybody can do to help. At the very least you should post the stored procedure that you have and an explanation of what you are trying to do.

Comment: What do you mean the ORIGINAL_LOGIN doesn't work? I would think this procedure does not need an inbound parameter at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All credits for hints to Sean Lange for this answer. I had to change the order of the two parts. First, SELECT then INSERT. Everything works now. Thank you, Sean.

```
create procedure procedure_who_gets_here
as
begin

-- part two, show user what he has to see
select * from dbo.MyTable

-- part one, get user data
insert into dbo.LoginsHistory
select 
getdate(), 
ORIGINAL_LOGIN()

end
```